# Запуск mongoDB в режиме InMemory

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB Enterprise 4.4.12

Хочу использовать режим InMemory. Вот мой файл конфигурации:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  engine: inMemory
  inMemory:
    engineConfig:
      inMemorySizeGB: 1
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

При запуске ошибка:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-27T10:11:05.027+04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"Location28662: Cannot start server. Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, but the specified storage engine was 'inMemory'."}}
```

MongoDB установлена на чистую систему, но потом была восстановлена база данных, созданная в режиме WT.
В чём проблема? Может база должна быть изначально создана в режиме InMemory? Тогда как базу трансформировать под InMemory mode?

Comment: Удалить файлы, которые были созданы до того, как был включен режим inmemory?

Comment: Спасибо! так и есть... конфликт в существующей базе WT. удалил, сделал mongorestore базы и всё заработало!